# Mockito java - test method call with different arguments

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm trying to test this method, to see if searchProfile is called without arguments:

```
public void searchProfile(Long searchTerm) {
    this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
    searchProfile();
}

public void searchProfile() {
     //...
}
```

This is my test case, I call the method with one argument and expect the one without the argument to be called

```
@Test
public void testSearchProfile() throws Exception {
    CustomerProfileController sutStub = Mockito.mock(CustomerProfileController.class);

    doNothing().when(sutStub).searchProfile();

    sutStub.searchProfile(0L);

    verify(sutStub, times(1)).searchProfile();
}
```

How can I make this work? Right now it just gives me an error:

> Comparison Failure:
>
> Expected: customerProfileController.searchProfile();
>
> Actual: customerProfileController.searchProfile(0);

Comment: I guess the accepted answer is correct in the sense that it fixes your problem. But why do you want to test a mock? Wouldn't it be better to test a concrete instance of `CustomerProfileController` and mock its depencencies, the way mocked testing is usually done?

Comment: @Magnilex you are right about that, I wanted to Spy on the methods instead. I've changed the test implementation all together after some research. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was about to add an answer saying that spying probably is a better choice, but the question didn't have enough context for me to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
Mockito.when(sutStub.searchProfile(Mockito.anyLong())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

When preparing the mock.

Comment: Great! This gave me the headstart to build my solution. It should be `doCallRealMethod().when(sutStub).searchProfile(Mockito.anyLong());` instead because of the `void` method. Thank you :)

Comment: Right, haven't notice it is void.

Comment: Maybe to use a spy is also an option for you